# How can I combine histogram and respective pdf in the same graph with the same scale?

Tags: graphics, histograms, pdf-format

I am trying to put the histogram and the pdf of the data together in the same grah in the same scale. The pdf is this actually:
[image]

However, as I put them in the same graph, it turns like this:
[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I try to do that however it gives the second graph again

Comment: I think that this is **not** a duplicate of the linked question -- @ecco wants a single y scale, while the other question is about having two axes that otherwise line up well.

Comment: Check out the first example in the documentation for Histogram under Applications.  Using `"PDF"` for the third argument of `Histogram` should give you something that can be combined with a plot of the PDF.

Comment: Your two plots don't look anything alike. The top has it's largest value at 0 and another peak at 0.1 while the histogram has largest peak near 0.05. Why should you expect them to line up nicely? The two are plotted on the same axes in the bottom plot.

Comment: @bills you are right. I put wrong figure sorry. I want two (histogram and pdf) of them to coincide so that I can see the peaks etc.

Comment: Hows this ?                                                                                                                                                                                                                               data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, "StandardGaussian"];
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -7, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red]]